# What command is sent from Android Wear when you click "Open On Phone"?

Tags: android, automation, command, tasker

I'm trying to make a tasker profile that sends a command to my PC to open different websites when I click the "Open on Phone" option. I'm going to set it up using an AutoWear command filter and Unified Remote. I'd like it to have it set that if I click the "Open on Phone" option for GMail, it opens gmail.com. Reddit will open reddit.com, etc. However, I don't know what command is sent from Android Wear to my phone to set the command filter, as well as how it identifies what application to open (probably com.*something*).

Does anyone know what the command is? It would be really helpful. Sorry if this isn't the right place to post. I saw a few threads about Android Wear on Google and figured it'd be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Open on Phone' option is an option on notifications posted from the phone to Android Wear. It triggers the [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) set with [setContentIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) and could link to anywhere (it is entirely up to each app developer) - but a deep link into an app is the most common as that same action is shared on the phone side when tapping a notification.

Comment: So, for example, if I received click the Open On Phone button for GMail, it would send: setContentIntent(com.google.android.gm) ?

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not how it works. As mentioned it could be **anything** at all. There's no pre-determined format, style, or even type of action.

Comment: Is there any way to find out what it is so I can create this profile? Any logs or something?